# Amazon Lambda for Lex Bot

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

i'm developing a AWS Lex Bot for managing an appointment scheduling application. To schedule an appointment the user must provide the bot with a data and a timeslot. Data are passed to a Lambda function that checks for availability and the ask for confirmation to the user if the slot is available or propose an alternative slot if it is not.
I've developed a python lambda function to manage the dialogue and the application logic, but I am strugling to build the confirmation logic because the bot

This is my sample code

else:

```
        isAvailable = 'True'
        
        if isAvailable == 'True':
            response = {
            "sessionState": {
                "dialogAction": {
                    "type": "ConfirmIntent"
                },
                "intent": {
                    'name':"scheduleAppointment",
                    'slots': slots
                },
                "message":{
                    "contentType": "PlainText",
                    "content": "Is it confirmed?",
                    }
                }
           }
        else
            response = {
            "sessionState": {
                "dialogAction": {
                    "type": "ConfirmIntent"
                },
                "intent": {
                    'name':"scheduleAppointment",
                    'slots': slots
                },
                "message": [
                      {
                    "contentType": "PlainText",
                    "content": "NewProposal",
                        },
                    ]
                }       
            }
    
        insert = addrecord_dynamodb_table(sessionID,Data,Time,Durata)
        return response
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? What exactly is the issue? Perhaps post some stacktraces so that we can see the errors you're having.